# LMC - Not going into negative (little man computer)

Tags: assembly, low-level, little-man-computer

Just working with Little Man Computer here and have ran into a problem that is kind of bugging me. Since there is no if's etc, I'm finding it hard to stop odd numbers going into negatives numbers when being subtracted from an even number. For example I take 3 off 10 in a loop and branch of at zero. But that never hits zero. So I want to know how to get the app to stop before it goes into negative, for example 3 subtracted from 10 in a loop will be 10, 7, 4, 1, -2. But I want it to stop at 1, therefore not going into negative and overcoming this problem.

This is what I have so far, and only works for even and even numbers:

```
INP
STA DEC
INP
LOOP SUB DEC
OUT
BRZ QUIT
BRA LOOP
QUIT HLT
DEC DAT
```

(to start off, I guess it would be a good idea to declare the second input as a variable, right? Or not?)

It would be greatly appreciated if you could help me out. And come up with a permanent solution to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know I'll regret this but since this seems fairly straight forward, I'll attempt this without being able to test :-)

```
INP
STA DEC
INP
LOOP SUB DEC
BRP OUTPUT
ADD DEC             <-- we went negative, so add back once
HLT
OUTPUT OUT
BRA LOOP
DEC DAT
```

Comment: what happens if the initial number is 10 and the decrement is 3? (10,7,4,1,-2 - still doesn't work)  It seems the OP has an untenable problem.

Comment: @KevinDTimm First time I hear of LMC so I've most likely missed something vital, but I can't see the problem with other values if things work like I figured it...? Subtracting and adding back at the end may not be beautiful, but I was shooting for straight forward.

Comment: You and me both, but I don't think the solution to his problem is straightforward - the OPs example would get to -2, a single increment wouldn't work, it would take 2 increments to get to zero - imagining the permutations on a Friday afternoon makes my brain cry. (hence the 'untenable' comment)

Comment: @KevinDTimm I'm not sure I understand what you mean :) DEC is a "variable", not an instruction, is that the cause of the confusion? Anyway, found a simulator at http://www.atkinson.yorku.ca/~sychen/research/LMC/LittleMan.html, seems to work when simulated :)

Comment: Works fine mate. Thank you very much. And I see what you guys mean, little man computer is a very, let me say vague language and being so vague has its positives and negatives, you need a hell of a lot of "work arounds".

Comment: @Deany If it solved your problem, please mark the question as solved. That's one way to keep people generally happy around here :)

Comment: Sorry about that, completely forgot. Also, would you be able to explain this line: BRP OUTPUT, i.e. why is it "OUTPUT". Is it just making "OUT" as a variable? Sorry, I just didn't understand that line.

Comment: @Deany OUTPUT is just a label that it can jump to, you could call it anything. Just called it OUTPUT to signify that I wanted to jump to where the data was output if the value was positive.

Comment: NB: it is not needed to do `ADD DEC` just before `HLT`. You can just do `HLT`.

Answer (score -1):

```
INP
STA first
INP
LOOP SUB first
BRP yesrepeat
ADD one
HLT
yesrepeat OUT
BRA LOOP
first DAT
one dat 001
```

Answer (score -1):

```
INP
STA DEC
INP
LOOP SUB DEC
OUT
BRP LOOP 
HLT
DEC DAT
```